# Cache hit rate for a set-associative cache: I don't understand this diagram

Tags: caching, memory, cpu-architecture

The title may not be very good but I couldn't find a better one.

We had homework to do and I didn't hand it in because I didn't understand it. Now because it's over, we got the solutions... And now I'm trying to understand the task using the solutions because trying to understand the complicated script of our professor is a waste of time for me.

---

The task:

> We have a direct mapped cache with following access frequency on main
>   memory blocks:
>
> ```
> 2 5 0 13 2 5 10 8 0 4 5 2
> ```
>
> What's the hitting quote (aka hit rate) if the cache is a
>   set-associative cache with set size 4 and FIFO?

From [my last question about direct-mapped caches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295373/how-exactly-to-count-the-hit-rate-of-a-direct-mapped-cache), I learned how to count the hit quote and wanted say thank you very much for it by the way.
My only problem for this is that I don't understand how the numbers are placed in the table like that.

I thought like programming maybe: 0-3 is array1 and other 0-3 is array2.
We take first number of the cache, 2 and put it in array1 so it is in array1[0]. Then we do same for the next number, take 5 and put it in array2[0]. Now take next number 0 and put in array`[1]`.

But as it seems the pattern is wrong, it's correct till line 4 of table but then it's wrong...

Why are the numbers placed like that in the table?

Solution: [image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It is a computer architecture question.

Comment: Strange because my other topic hasn't been closed and I've seen several topics like that on stack overflow.

Comment: You didn't provide enough information, but it looks like even addresses map to the first column and odd addresses to the second. Within each column it's just a FIFO. Assuming this is correct, what in particular is that you don't understand?

Comment: Ohh thank you Jester! 
Well maybe easy and clear for you to see that but not for me! :)
Maybe make your comment an answer so I can give you + and green mark.

Comment: If it is a waste of your time then it is not really worth knowing the answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you already asked how to interpret this question, and are not willing to work on understanding the answer.

Comment: I have already understood it dwelch.
Big thanks to Jester but also thanks to you for helping with my previous.
I don't force anyone to help me. I will write down everything I know and I try to understand. If you don't want help me then don't.

For the time waste, yeah reading professors script is a pure waste of time and I'm sure you would say the same. But what do you expect if he copy pastes a 10 year old script that hasn't even been created by him?
Also, it has about 10% to do with the tasks we get.
What people tell me here in few sentences is explained in his script in 30 pages..

Comment: if I'm lucky or it's not explained at all.

Comment: fair enough...if the professor is teaching this and you are taking this class he/she is your first resource.  I am as curious as you are and might be able to figure it out if more interested.  But your resistance to use the resource who is likely paid to do this job and instead lean on folks that are not paid for this, doing this for fun or to share the wealth.  That is my problem.   The prior answer did not cover the topic of how this works sufficiently?

Comment: In the prior answer, I knew how the table was created but I didn't know how to count the hitting quote. Now because of you guys, I know how it's done.
In this topic, I knew how to count the hitting quote (because of the previous one) but I didn't know how the table was created. 
Now I know how it's all done but actually I don't know why it's done like that exactly. Don't know how to get to that but surely not by reading his trash script. For this course, I always try bypasses like stack overflow, wikipedia and sometimes youtube. Note: It's not his so I shouldn't say his...

Comment: So you had an assignment.  You attended some classes to get this assignment.  I assume there were some lectures with the professor or someone who understood what they were teaching.  you didnt ask then.  you then didnt finish the assignment.  went to another class or more, didnt ask then, got the answer (during a class?), didnt ask then, didnt go after and ask?  Am I understanding this correctly?  It is at least a portion of these folks job to educate you.  I would seriously consider whether you should be paying tuition there if they are not doing their job...

Comment: dwelch you are right. But they don't explain or explain too complicated. I have already accepted that I'm not paying to learn. Instead, I'm paying to write the exams and hopefully pass them. Sounds a bit paradox yeah...
That's not for all my classes but this one yes.

Comment: The first line of your "task" says `We have a direct mapped cache`, but the last line says `if the cache is a set-associative cache with set size 4`.  The rest of the question isn't talking about a direct-mapped cache.  Can you edit this question to remove the misleading part?

Comment: @rpbudd: If the explanation given in class doesn't make sense, you should go to your professor's office during office hours and get him to explain it personally.  Stop him when you can't follow his explanation, so he knows exactly what to explain again in more detail / a different way.

Comment: Peter thanks for correction and edit, actually I double checked everything but didn't see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably wondering why the numbers don't line up with the addresses, as in the direct mapped case. What is going on in this diagram is that the items are placed into the sets left to right, that is all, because the sets are initially empty. The values 2, 0, 10 and 8 map to the leftmost set. The 2 appears first so it is in the leftmost column. Then 0 is placed in the next available position. 2 occurs again, and that is a "hit" indicated by the parentheses. Then 10 occurs and goes into the third spot. 8 goes to the fourth spot, and the cache block is now full. 0 recurs, and there is a hit, since it is still in the cache, in the second spot. Now 4 occurs. The cache set is full: something has to be kicked out. The 2 is kicked out (possibly due a least-recently-used (LRU) replacement policy) and replaced by 4. That is why the 4 is in the leftmost column; it has replaced the 2.  Now 2 occurs again and is no longer in the cache, since it was just kicked out. Now the least recently used cache item is 0, so **it** is kicked out and 2 now lives in the second spot.

Note that real four-way set-associative caches don't always use a full block-wide LRU replacement policy due to some further simplifications to speed them up.

And, by the way, the addresses are distributed into the sets according to simple modulo 4. It is not the case that even addresses go to the left set and odd to the right:

```
    set 0             set 1
0   1   2   3  |   0   1   2   3    <-   addr modulo 4
---------------+-----------------
0   1   2   3  |   4   5   6   7    <-   full addr
8   9  10  11  |  12  13  14  15
```

As you can see, this is consistent with what is in the table; except of course that the addresses don't match their modulo 4 position: they are given an arbitrary spot in each set based on the replacement policy.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, it opened my eyes and before I haven't even thought / knew what happens with the previous numbers and why some numbers (like 2 and 5) are placed in the same column, now understood.

What seems a bit unclear for me is the last part you mentioned with mod 4. 
So it's NOT true that even addresses are on the left, uneven on the right?

Comment: Never mind that, understood, everything is clear! :)