# Did I understand the meaning of a "cache line", "tag", "page", "frame", "block" correctly?

Tags: caching, memory, cpu-architecture, processor

As example I take picture of a direct mapped cache. These numbers were safed in it:

```
6 5 8 0 8 0 5 10 2 0 7 10
```

Now using this picture, I'd like to understand the given words in the title, I have read about them on several sites but the more I read the more it confused me. I thought it would be way easier to understand it using an example picture like this one.

1. Cache line: Amount of lines of the cache..? So in this case, we have 12 cache lines?
2. Tag: No idea..
3. Page: I don't know too..
4. Frame: Amount of numbers so we have here 0-7, so 8 frames?
5. Block: Is other word / same as page?

There are other words I forgot that fit here? Please help me this is no homework at all it's  desperate self study.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937002/how-does-direct-mapped-cache-work I think this question answers yours as well.

Comment: Ok thank you I understood tag too now. Only problem now is cache line. I'm not sure if it stands for.. line, so 12 lines here. Or if cache line = frames.. One of both must be right but don't know which. Please anyone tell me.

Comment: cache line: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_entries.  e.g. modern x86 CPUs use 64B cache lines in all levels of cache.  The wiki article is pretty big, and covers a lot of ground.

Comment: Future readers: the same user has [asked previous questions with this same diagram before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295373/how-exactly-to-count-the-hit-rate-of-a-direct-mapped-cache).  Even if this isn't technically homework, it's for a class with a professor.  So you should definitely check your textbook / ask your professor exactly how these terms are being used in a technical sense in your course.

Comment: See also [tag and index terminology for associative caches](https://web.archive.org/web/20131031045450/http://semipublic.comp-arch.net/wiki/Cache_Ways_and_Sets).  (Not applicable to your direct-mapped cache.  Well it sort of is, if you consider the special case of 0 index bits, so each set has only one tag.)  Link from [Paul Clayton's archive of Andy Glew's CompArch wiki](https://sites.google.com/site/paulclaytonplace/andy-glew-s-comparch-wiki).

Comment: I haven't heard for "frames" in this context.  I'm also not aware of a specific technical meaning for "block" in this context, so again, better ask your professor if you don't find it in the index of your textbook.

Answer (score -2):

Always reffer to [X86 Docs](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) if you have any problem about Intel architecture, it is very big, but answered any question I had. As I'm concerned, frame should be connected with stack frame.
You will see, that in manual Intel is using only expression: "cache line". 
And to be precise you should use that, instead of "cache frame".

Comment: This isn't an x86 question.  No recent Intel designs use a simple direct-mapped cache, and the x86 ISA manuals are not a good place to look for cache terminology for a computer architecture class.  They're definitely not specific about how the caches are designed, because that's not part of the ISA.  The optimization manual will describe some details of the caches in recent microarchitectures, but I don't think that will help the OP.

Comment: "stack frame" is the only context I've heard the word, too.  (Other than ethernet frames).  So clearly the OP is following some textbook that uses it to mean something specific about caches.